# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText

Tags: java, android

I have code to add the two numbers from the 2 text boxes together.

```
    public void sumNumbers(View v){
    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
    int calc1 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input1));
    EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
    int calc2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input2));
    int total = calc1 + calc2;
    String result = String.valueOf(total);
    EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
    output1.setText(result);
}
```

However when I launch the app and press the button, I crash with this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText{b412b358 VFED..CL ........ 292,60-392,100 #7f080041 app:id/input1}"
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
            at com.eren.addingmachine.MainActivity.sumNumbers(MainActivity.java:22)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help?

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please paste the below working code. I have just run and checked it.

```
public void sumNumbers(View v){
        EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
        int calc1 =  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input1.getText()));
        EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
        int calc2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input2.getText()));
        int total = calc1 + calc2;
        String result = String.valueOf(total);
        EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
        output1.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but why doesn't the above work, and what's the difference between using input2.getText and input2 alone?

Answer (score 0):

To get the text that the user enters into an `EditText`, you do *not* call `String.valueOf()`, passing in the `EditText`, as your code has. Instead, call `getText().toString()` on the `EditText`. You may still get exceptions, as the user may not have entered a valid `Integer`, but you will at least be closer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void sumNumbers(View v){
    try{
    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
    input1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    int calc1 =  Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString());
    EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
    input2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    int calc2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText().toString());
    int total = calc1 + calc2;
    String result = String.valueOf(total);
    EditText output1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
    output1.setText(result);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        Log.e("NumberFormatException" , e.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
```

in this way you can get values from edittext.

Instead of getting refrence to EditText in onClick event do this in onCreate() method of Activity.